How to set the Container App alocation to have 4CPUs and 8Gb of RAM in bicep
I'm trying to set the Container App allocation to 4CPUs and 8Gb of RAM in the consumption plan.
Through the Azure portal I managed to provision a Container App with that kind of resources, but when I try this using bicep, I get this error in the deployment of a Managed Application (through a Service Catalog Managed Application Definition)
"The total requested CPU and memory resources for this application (CPU: 4.0, memory: 8) is invalid. Total CPU and memory for all containers defined in a Container App must add up to one of the following CPU - Memory combinations: [cpu: 0.25, memory: 0.5Gi]; [cpu: 0.5, memory: 1.0Gi]; [cpu: 0.75, memory: 1.5Gi]; [cpu: 1.0, memory: 2.0Gi]; [cpu: 1.25, memory: 2.5Gi]; [cpu: 1.5, memory: 3.0Gi]; [cpu: 1.75, memory: 3.5Gi]; [cpu: 2.0, memory: 4.0Gi]"
I've tried to replicate what the portal has by exporting the ARM of the Container App that I provisioned using the portal, then de-compiling it to bicep and see what is missing, but with no luck so far. I've tested by adding the "workloadProfileName" and set it to 'Consumption', but the deployment fails with this error message: "Cannot specify workload profile name for container app in Consumption Only environment."
This is a section of my bicep file for the Container App
resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2023-05-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvironmentFullName
  location: location
  properties: {
    workloadProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'Consumption'
        workloadProfileType: 'Consumption'
      }
    ]
    appLogsConfiguration: {
      destination: 'log-analytics'
      logAnalyticsConfiguration: {
        customerId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.properties.customerId
        sharedKey: logAnalyticsWorkspace.listKeys().primarySharedKey
      }
    }
  }
}

resource functionsContainerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-05-01' = {
  name: testContainerAppFullName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    acrImport
  ]
  properties: {
    managedEnvironmentId: containerAppEnvironment.id
    configuration: {
      activeRevisionsMode: 'Single'
      secrets: [
        {
          name: 'application-insights-secret'
          value: applicationInsights.properties.ConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'app-registration-secret'
          value: appRegistrationSecret
        }
      ]
      registries: [
        {
          server: containerRegistry.properties.loginServer
          username: containerRegistry.name
          passwordSecretRef: 'registry-password'
        }
      ]
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          name: 'functions-'
          image: '${containerRegistry.properties.loginServer}/${containerAppImageName}:${containerAppTag}'
          resources: {
            cpu: 4
            memory: '8Gi'
          }
          env: [
            {
              name: 'ADMIN_TENANTS'
              value: adminTenants
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
      scale: {
        minReplicas: containerAppBackendMinReplicas
        maxReplicas: containerAppBackendMaxReplicas
      }
    }
  }
}

I've provisioned through the portal a Container App with 4 CPUs and 8Gb of RAM, exported the ARM template and decompiled it to BICEP, replicated the configuration, and tried to create the Container App.

Check if you can deploy through ARM and other scripts such as CLI and PowerShell.

Using your bicep file and setting workloadProfileName work for me. i was able to reprodue your issue as well without specifying it

can you delete the comtainer app env and retry?

I've deleted and recreated the container app, the resource group, and the Manage App Definition several times and the issue persists

You're missing the workloadProfileName property in the container app resource. This is required as you can have multiple workload profiles in the same container app environment:
resource functionsContainerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2023-05-01' = {
  name: testContainerAppFullName
  location: location
  ...
  properties: {
    ...
    workloadProfileName: 'Consumption'
    ...
  }
}

I imagine it is defaulting to Consumption Only plan when the workloadProfileName is not specified, see Azure Container Apps plan types
I has able to reproduce your issue using this template and commenting/uncommenting the workloadProfileName in the container app resource:
param location string = resourceGroup().location
param containerAppEnvironmentName string = 'cae-thomastest-001'
param containerAppName string = 'ca-thomastest-001'

resource containerAppEnvironment 'Microsoft.App/managedEnvironments@2024-03-01' = {
  name: containerAppEnvironmentName
  location: location
  properties: {
    appLogsConfiguration: {
      destination: 'azure-monitor'
    }
    workloadProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'Consumption'
        workloadProfileType: 'Consumption'
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource containerApp 'Microsoft.App/containerApps@2024-03-01' = {
  name: containerAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    environmentId: containerAppEnvironment.id
    // workloadProfileName: 'Consumption'
    configuration: {
      activeRevisionsMode: 'Single'
      ingress: {
        external: true
        targetPort: 80
      }
    }
    template: {
      containers: [
        {
          name: 'simple-hello-world-container'
          image: 'mcr.microsoft.com/k8se/quickstart:latest'
          command: []
          args: []
          resources: {
            cpu: 4
            memory: '8Gi'
          }
        }
      ]
      scale: {
        minReplicas: 0
      }
    }
  }
}


I have tested that approach (adding the workloadProfileName: 'Consumption' to the container app) and it fails with the same issue when provisioning the Managed Application

@GuntherW Added the template I used to reproduce your issue
